# Integral of Jacobi theta function is bounded

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

$θ(t) := \sum_{n=-∞}^∞ e^{−πn^2t}$ for $t > 0$.

(a) prove that  $\int_1^∞ |θ(t)−1|^p dt  $ is fintite for all $p>0$

(b) there exists $C_p$ for $0<p<2$ such that $\int_0^1  |θ(t)|^p dt ≤ C_p$

I think I have to use symmetry of theta function but I don't know how to use it.
On (a)  I came out with it is equal to $\int_0^1(|θ(1/t)−1|^p  t^{-2}) dt$ but I can't bound it to integrable function.

Comment: Hint for $(a)$: For $t\ge 1$, $$
\theta (t) - 1 = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - \pi n^2 t} }  \le 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - \pi nt} }  = 2\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \pi t} }}{{1 - {\rm e}^{ - \pi t} }} \le \frac{2}{{1 - {\rm e}^{ - \pi } }}{\rm e}^{ - \pi t} .
$$

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: how about (b) can i use  same method? -1 is not in (b)  and domain is 0,1 can i still bound it with similar series?

Comment: For $(b)$ you will need the transformation formula connecting $\theta(1/t)$ with $\theta(t)$. That will tell you how $\theta$ behaves near $0$ using its behaviour away from $0$.

Comment: then $\int_1^∞ (|θ(t)* t^{0.5}|^p  t^{-2}) dt$ ? is this finite?

Comment: $(\theta(t)\sqrt{t})^p t^{-2} \sim t^{-2+p/2}$ for large $t$. Do you know what power functions are integrable at infinity?